# How do I access parameters and methods defined across two interface from a class that implements those two interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net

In my factory I'm generating my object based on one interface, but it implements two.

for example

```
myClass1 : Interface1, Interface2 {
   string blah;
   int num;
}

myClass2 : Interface1, Interface2 {
   string blah;
   int num;
}

myClass3 : Interface1, Interface3 {
   string blah;
   bool truefalse;
}

interface Interface1 {
   string blah;
}

interface Interface2 {
   int num;
}

interface Interface3 {
   bool truefalse;
}
```

But in my factory I do this:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Interface1;
```

And then I have this object

```
Interface1 inter1;
```

But I want to do inter1.num but only have access to inter1.blah

Well basically I'm getting all the types that implement Interface 1 and getting a new instance of that functionality is the main one I'm interested in..  But after that I know those objects implement Interface 2 so I want access the properties and methods defined in that interface without recasting to the exact class object (because I don't know which one it is exactly)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to cast to the concrete class - just cast to the interface you're interested in (or use `as` to perform a conditional cast, and check it for success):

```
Interface1 x = (Interface1) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
Interface2 y = x as Interface2;
if (y != null)
{
     // Use y
}
```

Of course if you *can* refactor your interfaces - or provide a common interface which extends both of the other interfaces - that's better, but the above will work even if you're using interfaces which can't be changed.

Comment: Thanks, the alternative to refactor to common interface is better in terms of design principles or performance?

Comment: @erotavlas: Design. This sort of choice is rarely a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Create a common interface for your `Interface1` and `Interface2`

```
interface ICommon : Interface1,Interface2
{  } // you don't need to add anything here
```

Then implement this interface for your classses, instead of `Interface1` and `Interface2`, and use

```
Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ICommon;
```